# Change string order in a file

Tags: python, biopython

I have a file containing this structure, a fragment ID with his genes, for example r1 has 2 genes, r2 only one, etc :

```
r1
gene_1  1   181
gene_2  220 300
r2
gene_1  1   295
r3
gene_1  39  278
```

and I need to move each "r" string in front of his genes strings:

```
r1 gene_1   1   181
r1 gene_2   220 300
r2 gene_1   1   295
r3 gene_1   39  278
```

any ideas?

Comment: post code of what you have attempted then we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('path/to/input') as infile, open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.count('\t'):
            gene = line.strip()
            continue
        outfile.write(gene + '\t')
        outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    joined = ""
    for  ele in  f:
        if len(ele.split()) == 1:
            name = ele.rstrip()
        else:
            joined += "{} {}".format(name, ele)
    with open("in.txt","w") as f1:
        f1.write(joined)
```

output:

```
r1 gene_1  1   181
r1 gene_2  220 300
r2 gene_1  1   295
r3 gene_1  39  278
```